# Triggering all events together

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there is any quick fix for triggering all events of one element to another element.

```js
$("#inp-color").change(function(){
  alert($("#inp-color").val());
});
$("#inp-color").on("click", function(){
    alert($("#inp-color").val());
});

//blur, focus == other functios etc
```

```css
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .for-des-input {
    display: none;
  }
  .for-mob-input {
    display: block;
  }
}

.for-des-input {
  display: block;
}

.for-mob-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="for-des-input" id="inp-color">
<input type="text" class="for-mob-input" id="inp-color-2">
```

Here I want to trigger all events of `.inp-color` to `.inp-color-2` .

Is that possible?

currently what I am doing is

```
$("#inp-color-2").on("click",function(){
  $("#inp-color").trigger("click");
});

$("#inp-color-2").change(function(){
  $("#inp-color").trigger("change");
})
```

Comment: Why do you need to trigger multiple events?

Comment: Are you trying to define a custom event? It is not currently clear what you are trying to achieve. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine events into one `on()` and use the `event.type` in the handler callback to pass to `trigger()`

```js
// set up demo events
 $('div').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
      $(this).addClass('red')
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
      $(this).removeClass('red')
    },
    click:function(){
      $(this).append('<p>Clicked</p>')
    }
 });
 // anything done on first div is also triggered on second 
 $('#div1').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(event){
   $('#div2').trigger(event.type)
 })
```

```css
div{float:left; width:40%; border:2px solid #ccc}
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: thank you . is this is happen for only click event ? or it will for all events like change , blur etc ?

Comment: Whatever events you include in the `on()` for `#div1`

Answer (score 3):

Not getting your question quietly, but if you want to trigger the `change` event if any of your input is changed, then wrap your elements in a `div` and do something like

```
$(".all-inputs input[type=text]").change(function(){
  //code goes here if any input changes
});
```

Assuming that the wrapper has a `class` of `all-inputs`

Comment: sorry this is not possible.

Comment: @abilasher Explain *not possible*

Comment: because these input are placed in different divs . As the result i cannot made these in put in same div .

Comment: @abilasher So give those `div` the same `class` ?